# IndexOutOfBounds exception on ExpandableListView widget

Tags: android, widget

I'm using an `ExpandableListView` widget, which inflates child views based on the elements that are in a particular `ArrayList` (called `q`). This is working fine.

The issue is that, below all of the child views, I want to add an additional view. It seems like this should be pretty simple: In the adapter's `getChildrenCount()` method, I add `1` to the size of the relevant `ArrayList`. Then, in the `getChildView()` method, I use a switch (position) statement with 2 cases:

- A default case, which inflates regular child views for each object in the ArrayList
- A case: -1, which creates the special view (at the moment I'm just using a `TextView`), to be placed at the bottom.

However, I'm getting an `IndexOutOfBounds` error on the adapter, presumably because I haven't properly coded the changes to the `getChildrenCount()` and/or `getChildView()` methods. I suspect that it's looking for another array element (which doesn't exist) rather than inflating the special view as the last child.

Here is the code for the `getChildView()` and `getChildrenCount()` methods of the adapter. Let me know if you need to see the full code of the adapter.

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPos, int childPos, boolean arg2, View convertView,
        ViewGroup arg4) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        switch (childPos) {
        case -1:
            TextView post = new TextView(null);
            post.setText("post an answer");
            post.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            convertView = post;
            break;
        default:
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.answerbox, null);
        }

        TextView ansText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.answerText);
        TextView ansAuthor = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.answerAuthor);
        TextView ansUV = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.answerUpvotes);

        ansText.setText(q.get(groupPos).answers.get(childPos).text);
        ansAuthor.setText(q.get(groupPos).answers.get(childPos).author);
        ansUV.setText(Integer.toString(R.id.answerUpvotes));
    }
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return q.get(groupPosition).answers.size() + 1;
}
```

The `IndexOutOfBounds` error is being thrown at the following line:

```
ansText.setText(q.get(groupPos).answers.get(childPos).text);
```

Updated code (now working):

```
        @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPos, int childPos, boolean arg2, View convertView,
            ViewGroup arg4) {
        if (convertView == null){
        //switch (childPos){
        if (childPos == q.get(groupPos).answers.size()){
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.answerbox, null);            

            TextView ansText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.answerText);
            TextView ansAuthor = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.answerAuthor);
            TextView ansUV = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.answerUpvotes);

            ansText.setText("POST NEW");                    
            ansUV.setText(Integer.toString(R.id.answerUpvotes));
        }
        else{
        convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.answerbox, null);            

        TextView ansText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.answerText);
        TextView ansAuthor = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.answerAuthor);
        TextView ansUV = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.answerUpvotes);

        ansText.setText(q.get(groupPos).answers.get(childPos).text);
        ansAuthor.setText("by " + q.get(groupPos).answers.get(childPos).author);                    
        ansUV.setText(Integer.toString(R.id.answerUpvotes));
        }
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return q.get(groupPosition).answers.size()+1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problem with the `case -1`.

Android doesn't know that your last view is "fake" i.e. it isn't an actual element. Actually, `childPos` will `never` be `-1`! Your case for the last child should be:

```
if (childPos == q.get(groupPos).answers.size()) {
    // last view
} else {
    // regular view
}
```

You also have an issue which you'll discover later on:

You don't have covered the case when `convertView != null`. This will happen *often* and you should prepare yourself for it. It's the case when the list item view is recycled by the list view widget. In that case you should set it's values, not create a new item view.

Comment: Ha! I had figured this out myself, and was in the process of writing my own answer when you posted yours :) You mean that I shouldn't use a switch at all, but instead use an if statement to identify the "extra" view, right? Because this is what I did. I'm still learning Android obviously, and I'm not sure what you meant by this:     "You don't have covered the case when convertView != null. This will happen often and you should prepare yourself for it." Could you please explain what you meant?

Comment: @drewmore4 :D but really - be careful with the view recycling process - with your current code it won't update recycled view and you'll see stale views appearing at random positions because of this. you can peek at the `ApiDemos` samples from the SDK to code it properly.

Comment: Please see my updated code - this is how I have it working now. Might I still have that problem now?

Comment: yes! in short: it's an optimization for performance reasons - look at http://mobile.cs.fsu.edu/the-nuance-of-android-listview-recycling-for-n00bs/ for an a pretty good explanation. note: ViewHolder is just a helper class holding references to all dynamic views in the item view. it's a very common practice and I suggest you doing it along the example from this link.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is either with `q.get(groupPos)` or `answers.get(childPos)` as element has not been initialized at those positions

`IndexOutOfBound` exception is raised when you are trying to access an element in `ArrayList` at position `n` and no element had been initialized at that position